# Help with custom shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

Hello I would like some help setting up my custom shortcuts (well really finishing it) , so I set up a custom shortcut for Volume Up and Volume Down and it worked.

I set them up and with the correct commands, but I'd like it if it showed the volume status window thing when I volume up and down – I hope someone can help me with this.

To summarize this, I set up the shortcuts because the keyboard (internal for the laptop I'm using ) didn't work, so I set up the keyboard. But it doesn't show the volume kind of picture thing I'd really like to see. I hope this doesn't sound too hard, I just don't know how to do it.

Thank you for any support!

Comment: What  version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) Latest version of Linux Ubuntu I think! Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Using `pactl` sink number X to increase volume by **n** percent.

`pactl -- set-sink-volume X +n%`

---

Using `amixer` set **Master** to increase volume by **n** percent.

`amixer set 'Master' n%+`

---

Either way, decrease volume use `-` instead of `+`